# how to assign-static-ip-to-docker-container in docker-py

Tags: dockerpy

I think I know how to assign a static ip in docker.
Something like this seems to work:

docker run -it --rm --net=br0 --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --ip=172.27.153.11 mbussim

The problem is doing this in docker-py, which I think is just a python docker interface to docker.

In principle, docker-py tries to follow the docker lead:

You would think something like this would  work:

options = {
            "detach": True,
            "ip": "172.27.153.11",
            #"remove": True,
            "name": "mbussim_" + str(count),
            "cap_add": "NET_ADMIN"
            }
        }

```
       self.dockcon = self.dockerclient.containers.run(self.dimg, **options)
```

However, this does not work. Perhaps, this is not possible it docker-py?

Answer (score 1):

Following this seems to work.
First create an ip subnet:

```
ipam_pool = docker.types.IPAMPool(
    subnet='192.168.0.0/16',
    gateway='192.168.0.254'
)
ipam_config = docker.types.IPAMConfig(
    pool_configs=[ipam_pool]
)
client.networks.create(
    "mynet",
    driver="bridge",
    ipam=ipam_config
)
```

Now create the container the usual way:

```
container = client.containers.run("ubuntu", ["sh", "-c", command()], detach=True)
```

This by default attaches the container to a bridge network.
Now attach your container to your network and assign the static ip you want from the subnet.

```
client.networks.get("mynet").connect(container, ipv4_address="192.168.10.5")
```

Your container will now have 2 interfaces eth0 for the default network and eth1 having the mynet interface.
I am sure there must be an easier way to achieve this.